# CakePHP validate only part of model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.7

I want to update two fields, and only two fields, from a particular model in a form. There are many other fields on the same model that will get validated elsewhere, but these two fields are on a separate form.

I need them to match and both be present. `book_name_confirm` is not saved in the DB.

```
$validator
    ->scalar('book_name')
    ->maxLength('book_name', 255)
    ->requirePresence('book_name')
    ->sameAs('book_name_confirm', 'book_name', 'Book names must match')
    ->allowEmptyString('book_name', false);
```

Which seems to work fine when creating the record originally... but then when updating just those two fields, the validation does not seem to apply.

Example:

Name book "fluffy bunnies" and confirm and see record created in database. Validation happens as expected - putting in anything else in the confirm input returns the set error.

Go to book name update page.

Put in non-matching book names and submit, saves new book name. No error thrown. Can see new value displayed and in DB. Does throw a browser "must not be blank" error if you try to leave it empty.

The form itself:

```
<?= $this->Form->create($book) ?>
<fieldset>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->control('book_name');
        echo $this->Form->control('book_name_confirm', array('label' => 'Confirm book name'));
        ?>
</fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Set new book name')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

And the controller:

```
if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])){
    //bookTracking is passed through URL, is a UUID 
    $bookQuery = $this->Books->find('all')
        ->where(["tracking =" => $bookTracking]);
    $book = $bookQuery->first();
    //stuff here to handle missing books

    $book->book_name = $this->request->getData("book_name");
    $book->book_name_confirm = $this->request->getData("book_name_confirm");

    $this->Books->save($book);
    //redirect
} 

$book = $this->Books->newEntity();
$this->set(compact('book'));
```

I suppose I could do some manual validation in the controller, but that would seem to defeat the purpose of having the whole validation model thing set up. What am I missing?

Comment: Instead of setting the fields directly, try using the `patchEntity` function.

Comment: @GregSchmidt better, better enough I'd take that in the form of an answer for credit. Blocking saving mismatch, but not showing inline field error... might be completely separate issue.

Comment: @GregSchmidt, figured out missing error, was "newEntitiy()" down after the patch was called right before book was set.

Comment: Note that `->allowEmptyString('book_name', false)` has a deprecated argument order. The recommended order is now `->allowEmptyString($field, $message, $when)`, e.g. `->allowEmptyString('book_name', 'Book name cannot be blank', false)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set values directly, validation is not performed; it assumes that you knew what you were doing when you made those values. Instead, use the `patchEntity` function:

```
$book = $this->Books->patchEntity($book, $this->request->getData());
```